# Unable to launch Hive metastore with MySql empty password

Tags: mysql, hive, metastore

My local MySql do not have password for login, so I set hive-site.xml config for:

```
<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
    <value/>
<description>password to use against metastore database</description>
```

But After launching metastore with 
`hive --service metastore`

It always show there's password

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar:5.1.45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar:5.1.45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar:5.1.45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:873) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar:5.1.45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1710) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar:5.1.45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1226) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar:5.1.45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2188) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar:5.1.45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryO
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Sovled by add --hiveconf when start the server.

```
hive --hiveconf javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword= --service metastore
```